# Alternative to clipboard for sharing data between a web based application and legacy desktop application

Tags: java, web-applications, legacy

I've been pondering over this problem most the afternoon and haven't yet found the most ideal solution so thought I would see what others think..

There is a legacy Win16 application that has to be modified (with the least effort) in order to communicate with a web based application.

The idea is such that in the Win16 app, the user will want to look up a specific code, so they'll click a button which will then launch the browser and allow them to navigate a specific set of pages until they find the result they desire, then they have the option of either pressing Select or Cancel.

Pressing Select should pass back a small string back to the app (around 10 characters) and close the browser. Cancel will likewise send a Cancel message back to the app and again close the browser window.

I can't see many choices available in implementation as the Win16 app is not able to call webservices, so I'm looking at  using the clipboard, however that is not without problems.

I hope there's some other alternative I haven't thought of,

As always - all advice appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you call REST based web-services using plain-old HTTP?

Comment: We could, but it would require major redevelopment of the legacy app which is what we need to avoid.   I'm hoping we can launch the browser, let the user use the already existing web interface to finally reach a result they require and either select or cancel, with a message getting back to the legacy app.

Comment: Elaborate on Win16 app more please. Why is clipboard not welcome? What alternatives have you pondered? Or is it clipboard and NO alternatives?